# IE7 "Operation Aborted" even with FastInit?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

A piece of javascript code I'm working on is causing the nasty "Operation Aborted" message in IE. I am well aware that you cannot modify the DOM until after it has loaded. Sure enough the line of javascript code causing the error is the one which appends a new div tag to the body. However the function which the line is located within is called via FastInit.addOnLoad! I thought this meant the function would be called after the DOM was ready. Is there a better solution to this problem that using FastInit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N.B. SO is playing silly buggers with the formatting; sorry about that.

The "Operation Aborted" error occurs when you try to modify the grandparent element of the script element. So, for example, the following code will cause it because the script is attempting to modify the body from a child div, meaning it is trying to modify its grandparent element:

```
<body>
    <div id="foo">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var newThing = document.createElement("div");
        /* ### The next line will cause the error ### */
        document.body.appendChild(newThing);
        <script>
    </div>
</body>
```

The same code changed to:

```
<body>
    <div id="foo">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var newThing = document.createElement("div");
    /* ### The next line will NOT cause an error ### */
    document.body.appendChild(newThing);
    <script>
</body>
```

would *not* cause the error, as the script is now modifying its parent, which IE can handle.

The most common reason for this happening is that you have failed to close a `div` (or other element) further up the page; find the missing close tag and you'll fix it. Alternatively, if your script actually *is* inside another element, move it out so it is a child of the `body`.

Comment: The script in questions is in the <head> and is called via FastInit so the DOM should be ready already.

Comment: FastInit has to use some pretty weird tricks to get a simulation of DOMready on IE. The definitive Microsoft explanation of the causes for this error is at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917

Comment: @NickFitz: The Microsoft document seems to refer to scripts that are grandchildren (or deeper) of the body. My script is a child of the <head> tag. Are you saying my script should be a child of the <body> tag instead? It appears to me that article doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @NickFitz putting the script in the body tag didn't help, unless it was the very last item in the DOM.

Comment: I ended up just putting the script tag as the final element in the DOM... still don't know why this wasn't work in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about FastInit, but I just answered a similar question about waiting for the DOM to be ready here:

[Initiate onclick faster than with document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153858/initiate-onclick-faster-than-with-document-onload/1153988#1153988)

Basically, you can do it in IE by using the defer attribute on your script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
</script>
```

This will delay parsing the script until after the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Josh: fastInit already uses that trick to work out when to trigger on IE: you can see it at the bottom of the FastInit source in a "document.write".

Comment: @NickFitz: that's what I thought -- which is why I was confused as to why this isn't working.

Comment: @Andy, unfortunately, the defer tag didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry...

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Your code??
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to wait until all images have loaded. Also, when I do window.onload, sometimes my code is never actually run!